# Angular - function in a component not working properly for ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am Angular begginer and working on a simple app that allows to rate the books. I encountered the problem once tried to insert a function to a controller that is inside a component. The function should increase 'likes' number and show it in the paragraph with class 'likes'. However, when I added ng-click function, it seems to be changing the value of a previous element (e.g. when I click on 'likes' on element 1, likes counter in element 0 changes). Can you take a look and advise what may be wrong?

Here is the component:

```
angular.
module('booksList').
component('booksList', {
    templateUrl: 'books-list/books-list.template.html',
    controller: function BooksListController() {
        this.products = [
            {
                name: 'The Book of Trees',
                price: 19,
                pubdate: new Date('2009', '03', '08'),
                cover: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61EQH6%2BCpuL._SX376_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                likes: 0,
                dislikes: 0
            },
            {
                name: 'Program or be Programmed',
                price: 8,
                pubdate: new Date('2013', '08', '01'),
                cover: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41dKoLBVToL._SX362_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                likes: 0,
                dislikes: 0
            },
            {
                name: 'Sacred Games',
                price: 40,
                pubdate: new Date('2011', '09', '02'),
                cover: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MQoLSldhL._SX327_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                likes: 0,
                dislikes: 0
            },
            {
                name: 'Shantaram',
                price: 20,
                pubdate: new Date('2010', '08', '02'),
                cover: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51GEFhAifOL._SX332_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg',
                likes: 0,
                dislikes: 0

            }
        ];        
        this.orderProp = 'name';        
        this.plusOne = function(index) {            
            this.products[index].likes += 1;
            console.log(this.products[index].likes);            
        }
    }
});
```

And here is html template that I use function in:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in $ctrl.products | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.orderProp">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img ng-src="{{product.cover}}" alt="{{product.name}}">
        <p class="title">{{ product.name }}</p>
        <p class="price">{{ product.price | currency }}</p>
        <p class="date">{{ product.pubdate | date }}</p>
        <div class="rating">
            <p class="likes" ng-click="$ctrl.plusOne($index)">+{{product.likes}}</p>
            <p class="dislikes" ng-click="$ctrl.minusOne()">-{{product.dislikes}}</p>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you recreate this in a plunker/fiddle, because currently I can't see an issue from just looking at it...

Comment: Pass in product instead. It's easier and less confusing.

Comment: You're filtering and reordering the array when you render it which means that `$index` is not the same as the object's index in the `products` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of index,

```
   ng-click="$ctrl.plusOne($index)"
```

pass product itself

```
   ng-click="$ctrl.plusOne(product)"
```

and rewrite function as below

```
    this.plusOne = function(product) {            
        product.likes += 1;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. Can you explain why it wasn't reffering to an index properly? I checked the items had proper indexes so it's quite confusing for me

Comment: @Joanna, please have a look to my answer.

Comment: @joanna its the filtering caused the problem i think. You can refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MzqkIZLkBsU&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWKHkcL7RJmmXyxkuFB3KSl&index=6 to know how  '$index' works

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to include `track by $index`.

`track by $index` is used in order to link your data with the DOM generation (and mainly re-generation) made by `ng-repeat`.

In your case `$index` is an `identity` key in order to distinguish the `items` in your `array`.

**If you don't have a unique identifier, `track by $index` can also provide a performance boost.**

Here is [working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/tjruzpmb/542/).

Comment: I think this did not exactly asnwer my question because when I only have a controller it works fine (when I refer to $scope as in your example). But when I put controller in the component and then use only the compontent (with html template) in the site, the index is not changing properly. I think the issue may be caused by filtering and reordering as Titus suggested above.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. Another solution is to assign a `id` property for every product.